# Where is the best place to hold system-wide helpers\libs in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm refactoring on old Rails app, and I have a lot of little methods\helpers that keep piling up that are not controller\model specific but are rather system-wide specific.

For instance I have a method that determines whether the system is Windows or not:

```
def windows?    
     (/win|mingw/).match(RUBY_PLATFORM) ? true : false
end
```

I use it in a few places to setup platform specific configuration, such as absolute executable path for wicked_pdf and gbarcode, etc, etc. The point is it's system wide and can be used anywhere.

Some people say put it in environment, some in lib, some in application helper, some say roll out a gem or plugin.

What is the consensus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this [post](http://blog.stonean.com/2008/03/20/rails-where-do-i-put-my-code/) as a guideline.

Basically, anything not specific to controllers/models that is application specific, put in lib.

If the class/module will be used in multiple applications then make a gem/plugin.

Comment: The link provided above is no longer active.

Comment: The summary of that post was - use lib/my_custom_classes.rb to put code like that in. and make sure you load it from applicaiton.rb, otherwise use a gem. Which I created for my helpers http://rubygems.org/gems/santas_little_helper

Comment: archived version of post http://web.archive.org/web/20100109100521/http://blog.stonean.com/2008/03/20/rails-where-do-i-put-my-code/